# Can we restructure destructured parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have destructured my parameters in a function like so:

```
const obj = {a:1 , b:2, c:3, d:4}
function1(obj);

function1 ({a , b, c ,d}) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

now i need to pass all my params into another function. Is there a way I can acheive something like this?

```
const obj = {a:1 , b:2, c:3, d:4}
function1(obj);

function1 ({a , b, c ,d}) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  func2(allMyParams) //instead of func2({a,b,c,d})    
}
```

Comment: Consider destructuring in the function body?

Comment: please add an example of the call of function without name and `function1`. it is quite unclear if you hand over an array or a single object and what signature do you have for `function1`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `arguments` array like object, which contains all passed parameters, since you passed 1 parameter, you can pass it to another function via `arguments[0]`

```js
function asd ({a , b, c ,d}) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  aa(arguments[0]) 
}

function aa(a) {
  console.log(a);
}

asd({a:1,b:2, c:3, d:4});
```